# Android post variables to drupal

Tags: java, android, iphone, cocoa

Hi I'm writing an app for both iOS and Android to interface with a druapl site. I'm trying to allow users to login to the website and then save the data from successful logins in the preferences of the app. Below I was able to successfully do what I wanted in Cocoa but I have been unable to get it to work in Java. Both code snippets are below. Any help with the java would be greatly appreciated.

I'm just not getting any response at all from the java the response comes back as an empty string when it should be a long JSON response.

**Cocoa Login (Working)**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://examplesite/api/rest/user/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSData *requestBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[userField text],[passField text]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

**Java Login (Not Working)**

```
class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {   
    HttpResponse response;
    public loginTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://examplesite/api/rest/user/login");
        try {
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (formparams));
            response = client.execute(post);  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        //TODO finish the activity
        try {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What errors are you experiencing? Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cocoa but it looks like you're sending a string "username=user&password=pass" in your request in Cocoa, and a JSON object in your request in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's things for this like. Drupal iOS sdk and dandy for android

Comment: installed drupal ios sdk on my project and already successfully logging in a much better solution thank you will try dandy after finishing adapting the ios app

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples you've listed you aren't submitting the same payload on iOS and Android.

On iOS you are correctly POSTing form data with `username=foo&password=bar`, but on android you are asking for the string representation of your `JSONObject` which is `{ 'username': 'foo', 'password':'bar' }`.

Rather than using a JSONObject you should checkout [URLEncodedUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html), in particular the `format` method.

Comment: I edited it to how i think it should be now but it's still not working